# Python: why isn't my if statement running

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been trying to write basic settings for my code and for some reason my if statement isn't working. I am pretty sure that my mistake is really stupid, but I can't find it.

```
elif menu == 3:
    set1 = 3
    print("1.Restart the program automatically")
    print("2.Restart the program manually")
    while set1 != 1 or set1 != 2:
        set1 == int(input("Please enter your choice:"))
    if set1 == 1:
        print("Set 1 works")
    elif set1 == 2:
        print("Set 2 works")
    else:
        print("Smash the monitor")
print("Goes to the main body")
```

Comment: You want `and`, not `or`: if `set1 == 2`, then `set1 != 1` is true and the loop will continue.

Comment: Less confusing would be `while set1 not in [1, 2]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two mistakes you need to fix.

1. change `while set1 != 1 or set1 != 2:` to `while set1 != 1 and set1 != 2:` otherwise it will never stop.
2. change `set1 == int(input("Please enter your choice:"))` to `set1 = int(input("Please enter your choice:"))`

now everything is Ok. final code must look like this:

```
elif menu == 3:
    set1 = 3
    print("1.Restart the program automatically")
    print("2.Restart the program manually")
    while set1 != 1 and set1 != 2:
        set1 = int(input("Please enter your choice:"))
    if set1 == 1:
        print("Set 1 works")
    elif set1 == 2:
        print("Set 2 works")
    else:
        print("Smash the monitor")
print("Goes to the main body")
```